# What's the opposite to ChannelFactory<TChannel>.CreateChannel?

Tags: c#, wcf, channelfactory

I just followed [this](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) tutorial and played a little bit with the code. I'm almost sure I read somewhere that there is a timeout for the channel, so it might get automatically closed eventually. So I tried simply opening a new channel in my client for each method I wanted to invoke, and eventually (after lots of calls) I got errors.

Seems like there is a limit on how many channels I can have open at the same time. But since the channel is an instance of a custom object, I don't see how can I close it or kill it or whatever I need to do with it to get rid of it so I can create other channels.

Then I noticed on the `CreateChannel` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa344556.aspx) that my `TChannel` should implement `IChannel` (which the tutorial I linked above doesn't do). So, is this how I would close my channel? If so, how would I close it or what should I do on my implementation of the `Close` method? And what should I do on the implementation of every other method if I do have to implement the interface?

Or should I just use a single channel for as long as it lasts? Anyway, how am I supposed to know whether is faulted or open or closed if all I have is an instance of my own class?

As you can see I'm pretty lost on the subject so I hope you can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ChannelFactory<TChannel>.CreateChannel` creates and return a channel of your specified service type. The returned object already implements `IChannel`. You (normally?) don't need to implement your own `Close` method, nor any other methods of `IChannel`.

Normally you don't create a new channel for every call, you just re-use it. (Only in some specific cases it may be better to create a new channel for every call).

You can close the channel by casting it to `IClientChannel`. Use this pattern:

```
try
{
  ((IClientChannel)channel).Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ((IClientChannel)channel).Abort();
}
```

You can use `((IClientChannel)channel).State` to get the state of the channel (i.e. `CreatedOpened`, `Faulted`, `Closed`).

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a try later since I'm afk now. Anyway how do u get to know this kind of stuff? Can't find much info on the documentation. I don't want to have to ask for ever little think I do. Is this the kind of info u only find in books?

Comment: I use several sources that I found over time through searches like CodeProject.com, MSDN, dotnetconsult.co.uk. And of course the greatest source of all... StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

Peladao basically hits the nail on the head.

To clarify some of what he is saying, CreateChannel will create a (proxy) object which implements both your custom service interface *and* IClientChannel.

Typically you do keep the channel open and reuse its calls.  Beware also that once it enters a fault state there is no recovery, you must open a new channel.  As Peladao mentions a fault state can be detected via ((IClientChannel)channel).State, and also don't forget you'll generally get an exception too.

If memory serves, the debug process for WCF accepts 10 simultaneous channels for a service.